# How to update LiveData by set a value to variable

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have a variable and a LiveData, and I want to update the LiveData when I set a value to the variable.

```
var trigger = ""
val updateValue: LiveData<Value> = service.getValue(trigger)

// when set the value1 to trigger, the updateValue need to update the value.
var trigger = "value1"
val updateValue: LiveData<Value> = service.getValue("value1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `switchmap`:

```
var trigger = MutableLiveData<String>()
val updateValue: LiveData<Value> = Transformations.switchMap(trigger) {
        service.getValue(it)
}
```

Then:

```
trigger.value = "value1"
```