# is there any way to initialize room livedata with variable in viewmodel?

Tags: android

I want to initialize my room livedata when I call the method. I know the way to initialize a room livedata when the viewmodel create like this.

```
    private val _playList : MutableLiveData<List<PlayListEntity>> = MutableLiveData()
    var playList :LiveData<List<PlayListEntity>>  = apiRepository.selectPlayListByFolderId(1)
```

but I want to change this when calling method, because the query will be a different regarding to ID.
Is there any way to solve this?

here is my viewmodel code

```
class FolderMusicViewModel @Inject constructor(private val apiRepository: ApiRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _playList : MutableLiveData<List<PlayListEntity>> = MutableLiveData()
    var playList :LiveData<List<PlayListEntity>>  = _playList//apiRepository.selectPlayListByFolderId(1)


    fun getPlayList(folderId :Int){
        playList = apiRepository.selectPlayListByFolderId(folderId)
       
    }

 
}
```

Comment: You can use `switchMap` as I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63898566/994939

Comment: thank you bro. I solved it. I will study for switchmap.

Answer (score 0):

veritas1 helped.

```
   private var _folderId : MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()
   
   private val _playList : MutableLiveData<List<PlayListEntity>> = MutableLiveData()
   var playList :LiveData<List<PlayListEntity>>  = Transformations.switchMap(_folderId){
       apiRepository.selectPlayListByFolderId(_folderId.value!!)
   }


   fun getPlayList(folderId :Int){
       _folderId.value =folderId
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of using a LiveData in your ViewModel is:

1- Changing private MutableLiveData instead of the public one.

2- You must change the get function of public live data

3- the response of the API repository must be a string instead of LiveData. If you want it to be a LiveData you can change the private LiveData as well.

Take a look at the code:

```
class FolderMusicViewModel @Inject constructor(private val apiRepository: ApiRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _playList : MutableLiveData<List<PlayListEntity>> = MutableLiveData()
    val playList :LiveData<List<PlayListEntity>> 
           get() = _playList


    fun getPlayList(folderId :Int){
        _playList.postValue(apiRepository.selectPlayListByFolderId(folderId))
    }
}
```